# Creating a multiplication function in an angularjs controller?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a multiplication function in an angularjs controller. I want the function to return the product of quantity and price. I'm using the snippet below, but it's returning an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html> <html>

 <head> <script src= "Angular.js"></script> </head>

 <body>

 <div ng-app="" ng-controller="personController">

 <h2>Cost Calculator</h2>

 Quantity: <input type="number" ng-model="quantity"> Price: <input type="number" ng-model="price">

 <p><b>Total in dollar:</b> {{fullname()}}</p>

 </div>


 <script> function personController(scope) {    var input1 =  scope.quantity ,    var input2 = scope.price ,
     $scope.fullName = function() {
         return {{input1 * input2}};
     } } </script>

 </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this simple example you do not need to create a controller.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pd2yzfLx/)

```
<h2>Cost Calculator</h2>
Quantity:
    <input type="number" ng-model="quantity">Price:
    <input type="number" ng-model="price">
    <p><b>Total in dollar:</b> {{quantity*price}}</p>
</div>
```

But, if you need create it - see mistakes:

- angulars interpolation syntax `{{ }}` is only used in HTML, not javascript.
- Use `$scope`, not `scope`
- formatting your code is important.

Comment: no i want it in a script to store the result in a variable to reuse it again

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using the [currency filter](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/docs/api/ng/filter/currency). You might also want to take a look at the [number filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number).

Note: Starting in angular 1.3.0 the [currency filter](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/api/ng/filter/currency) lets you add a fractionSize.

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('personController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.price = 0;
  $scope.quantity = 0;
  
  
  $scope.total = function() {
    return $scope.price * $scope.quantity;
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personController">
  <h2>Cost Calculator</h2>
  Quantity: <input type="number" ng-model="quantity"> 
  Price: <input type="number" ng-model="price">

  <p><b>Total in dollars:</b> {{ total() | currency : $ }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not using `$scope`? thats not local variable  that is injected `$scope` so name cannot be changes as we do with the argument names of loval variables

There were syntax errors as well i have refactored your code

**Working demo**

```js
angular.module('test',[]).controller('personController', function ($scope) {    
     $scope.price = 0;
     $scope.quantity=0
 
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>

<head> <script src= "Angular.js"></script> </head>

<body>

<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="personController">

<h2>Cost Calculator</h2>

Quantity: <input type="number" ng-model="quantity"> Price: <input type="number" ng-model="price">

<p><b>Total in dollar:</b> {{quantity*price}}</p>

</div>




</body> </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> function personController(scope) {
    var input1 =  scope.quantity;,
    var input2 = scope.price;
    $scope.fullName = function() {
        return {{input1 * input2}};
    }
 }
 </script>

</body> </html>
```

There is a clear syntax error here which is {{input * input2}}. This is angularjs expression syntax, not javascript syntax. Try just using input * input2. You are also referring to $scope which is not available, so change to 'scope':

```
    scope.fullName = function() {
        return input1 * input2;
    }
```

Or, you could refer to the scope variables directly

```
    scope.fullName = function() {
        return scope.quantity * scope.price;
    }
```

Or you could refer to them directly in the template:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> <html>

<head> <script src= "Angular.js"></script> </head>

<body>

<div ng-app="">

<h2>Cost Calculator</h2>

Quantity: <input type="number" ng-model="quantity"> Price: <input type="number" ng-model="price">

<p><b>Total in dollar:</b> {{quantity * price}}</p>

</div>

</body> </html>
```